# Ограничение движения блока

Tags: javascript

Есть фиксированный обьект, при опускании вниз, он залазит на футер, нужно остановить перед футером

```
<div id="float-block" class="float-block">
    бал бла
</div>
```

Js

```
var scrollFloat = function () {
'use strict';

var app = {};

app.init = function init (node) {
    if (!node || node.nodeType !== 1) {
        throw new Error(node + ' is not DOM element');
    }
    handleWindowScroll(node);
};

function handleWindowScroll (floatElement) {
    window.onscroll = function () {
        if (window.scrollY > floatElement.offsetTop) {
            floatElement.style.position = 'fixed';
            floatElement.style.bottom = '0';

        } 
        else {
            floatElement.style.position = '';
            floatElement.style.top = '';
        }
    };
}

return app;
}();
```

Comment: так проверяй еще одно условие с высотой футера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант для смещения фиксированного блока, для просмотра запустить код и проскролить вниз

```js
var scrollFloat = function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = {};

  app.init = function init(node, footer) {
    if (!node || node.nodeType !== 1) {
      throw new Error(node + ' is not DOM element');
    }
    handleWindowScroll(node, footer);
  };

  function handleWindowScroll(fixed, footer) {
    var top = fixed.getBoundingClientRect().top,
      topEnd = footer.getBoundingClientRect().top - fixed.offsetHeight - top;
    window.onscroll = function() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > topEnd) {
        fixed.style.top = topEnd + top - window.pageYOffset + "px"
      }

    };
  }

  return app;
}();
scrollFloat.init(document.querySelector('.fixed-block'), document.querySelector('.footer'))
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}
p {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.fixed-block {
  border: 1px dashed Gray;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
}
.footer {
  background: #F00;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-block">
  fixed
</div>
<div class="footer">footer
  <p>Copyright (c) 2013</p>
</div>
```